# Potential of the Plates of a Parallel plate capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential, capacitance

Imagine two large metal plates having charge density $+\sigma$ and $-\sigma$ placed close to each other with a distance $d$ between them. The question is that why are the two plates are at **different** potentials. If a charge $+q$ is brought by an external force from infinity to the $+ve$ plate from the opposite side of the $-ve$ plate, the force experienced by the charge should be zero as the the $+ve$ and the $-ve$ plates exert an equal and opposite force of $q\sigma/2\epsilon_0$ on the charge. So the work done is **zero for either of the plates**. The work done or potential should not change when the charge is brought from any side of the plate as both are state functions. But Electric Field **does exist** in between the plates. And it should because one plate has $+ve$ charges while the other has $-ve$. So there must be a potential difference in between them.

I know that I have made two contradictory statements above but I can't understand  what's wrong in my understanding. Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are facing this apparent contradiction is because you are bringing your test charge $+q$ to the plates from two different directions. In one case you start at $-\infty $ and in the other, at $+\infty $ You have to start from one **fixed** direction **relative to which** you assign all other potentials in space. Conventionally, this is chosen to be $+\infty $. The electric field outside the capacitor is zero, and inside it is $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$. You take your test charge from $+\infty $ to the negatively charged plate, without feeling any force. The potential here is 0. Then you *continue to move it in the same direction*, encountering an electric force $\frac{q\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$ for a distance $d$. Work at the negative plate is $0$, so this is assigned a potential $0$. Then *an additional work* was done taking the charge from $-$ to $+$ plate, so that the potential (work per unit charge) at the  $+$ plate is in an excess of $\frac{d\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$ relative to the $-$ plate and is assigned a potential of $\frac{d\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$ . Hence the potential difference between the plates of $\frac{d\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$ . Remember, potentials are assigned *relative to a **fixed** point*, not arbitrarily.

Comment: I understand it now. Potential is measured with one "fixed" point, i.e. +infinity assuming it anywhere far. Work done for the force to move the charge from the "fixed" point to any one plate say +ve is zero, then it will be $-qd$$\sigma$/$\epsilon_0$ for the other. Thanks for answering my query.